# Install additional software in Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, yum, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I have created Amazon Linux instance on Amazon Lightsail cloud. Now I would like to install Mosquitto buy entering command:

```
sudo yum install mosquitto
```

But system codn't find it.

UPD

I tried to add epel repository:

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/e
pel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Got output:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No such command: mosquitto. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help
[ec2-user@ip-172-26-11-216 ~]$ sudo yum install mosquitto
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
822 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mosquitto.x86_64 0:1.6.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1
.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86
_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebsockets.so.13()(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7
.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libwebsockets.x86_64 0:3.0.1-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libuv.so.1()(64bit) for package: libwebsockets-3.0.1-2.el7.x86_
64
---> Package mosquitto.x86_64 0:1.6.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1
.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86
_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libuv.x86_64 1:1.33.0-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package mosquitto.x86_64 0:1.6.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1
.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86
_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.6.7-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install a package with `yum`, it has to be available in one of your repositories, which is obviously not the case. On their website I don't see any `rpm` repository however (only for debian). So in this case I think you'll have to install it manually using the **binary** installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the properly `repository`. In first instance you can try to add the `epel` repository. Try with `sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`, now you can type `sudo yum install epel-release`. Than run an update and retry to install your software. If is still not found, than you have at least three solution:
- search for the repository (if provided by the vendor) that the software belong. In this method you get updates directly from yum in case of new software release.
- download ad install manually the RPM related to the software
- compile from source.